# How to Store Data in Client Side Database in JSON Web Services

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

I have a Client side page and i have fields like empname,address,sex etc., if we click on Create button the Employee data should store in Database..For that purpose i write a class "EmployeeModel" and taken fields written properties and in client side i added service reference and in that .aspx.cs i writeen something like this:

```
    EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel();
    emp.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    emp.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
    emp.Address = txtAddress.Text;
    emp.DateOfBirth1 = txtDOB.Text;
    emp.Sex = rdbtnGender.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

After that what steps i have to write to store Employee data in DATABASE.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make call from client side to server using below javascript code

```
$.ajax({
               type: "get",
               url: "?ajax_mode=SaveMyData,
               dataType: "json",
               async: false,
               data: { headerData: JSON.stringify(emp) },
               cache: false,
               success: function(data, textStatus) {
                   if (data.status == "success") {

                   }
                   else {

                   }
               }
           });
```

Now handle savemydata function to save info of employee

```
Public Sub SaveMyData()

    Dim objHeaderPostData As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim strParams As String = Request("headerData")
    Dim objOutput As New Ajax.BasicAjaxObjectOuput

    Dim jsS As New JavaScriptSerializer : objHeaderPostData = CType(jsS.DeserializeObject(strParams), Dictionary(Of String, Object))

    Dim strFirstName as string = CStr(objHeaderPostData.Item("FirstName"))
    '' get same way other infor from object objHeaderPostData



    Dim objOutput As New BasicOuputObject
    Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim lstMyData As New List(Of MyData)
    Dim objMyData As MyData
    Dim objConn As New SqlConnection("Pass Connection String")
    objCommand.CommandText = '' write insert or update command as per requirement
    objCommand.Connection = objConn

    objConn.Open()
    objCommand.ExecuteScalar()



    objOutput.errorMessage = ""
    objOutput.obj = "Successfylly save record."
    objOutput.strMessage = "success"

    Dim objSerialiser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(objSerialiser.Serialize(objOutput))
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End()

End Sub
```

Hope this will help you.

more info about json you can visit my blog [here](http://prakashpatani.blogspot.com/)

Comment: yes..its using jquery ..u can download it for free and add to your aspx page.